# GAUSSIAN 16 Error with CCSD(T)

Tags: gaussian, optimization

My input file is:

```
%CPU=8
#P SCF=TIGHT CCSD(T)/aug-cc-pVTZ Opt(ReadOptimize,tight,z-matrix)

h2o test 3

0 1
O
H                  1    B1
H                  1    B1     2  A1

B1 0.96000000
A1 109.50000032

atoms=3 notatoms=1,2
```

And I am getting this error:

```
 ************************************************
 ** ERROR IN INITNF. NUMBER OF VARIABLES (  0) **
 **   INCORRECT (SHOULD BE BETWEEN 1 AND 50)   **
 ************************************************
```

I followed [these instructions](https://www.somewhereville.com/2012/04/29/ccsdt-and-mp4-z-matrix-coordinate-oddity-in-gaussian-when-in-doubt-change-your-format/). But, they did not work for me.

**What is wrong with my input? **

Comment: Hi, do you want a full optimization (i.e. no any coordinate constraint), or just want to optimize some geometry variables? Answers depend on your optimization target.

Comment: Hi @jxzou , I want to optimize only the second hydrogen.

Answer (score 2):

Non-gradient optimizations only work in internal coordinates, and if you only want the last H to optimize, you cannot have the B1 variable to also define atom 2.

Answer (score 2):

### **TL/DR** You cannot easily do optimisations with CCSD(T) in Gaussian. Try a different method instead (CCSD perhaps).

Gaussian only supports numerical gradients for CCSD(T), and the optimisation procedure defaults to the 'EigenvalueFollow' (Opt=EF) procedure when analytic gradients are not available. This method is limited to solving max 50 variables, which is likely too be too few for a 'real' complex molecule. See http://www.ccl.net/chemistry/resources/messages/2012/03/13.016-dir/index.html. Non-analytic optimisations are also famously, painfully slow. Unless you are really interested in solving the structure of water, I would recommend using a method with analytic gradients instead (pretty much anything other than CCSD(T), MP5 and MP4 I think).

### Also

`%CPU=8` requests the calculation run only on CPU 8 (ie, one CPU max). If you instead wanted to run a parallel calculation using 8 CPUs, you want:

`%NProcShared=8`

Answer (score 1):

Are there any extra empty lines after the final line you've posted? In my experience, you need to add a few empty lines at the end of your input file if you want the calculation to work.

In other words, the last part of your input should look like this:

```
0 1
O
H  1  B1
H  1  B1  2  A1

B1 0.96000000
A1 109.50000032

atoms=3 notatoms=1,2
```

(Note the extra lines below the end of the input.)

That being said, if your plan is to optimise one O–H bond and not the other, you should probably add a `B2` variable to your input, otherwise I'm not sure anything other than the angle will change.